# Hyper-V : make public a VM (at least one port)

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I have HyperV and I have to make available to the Internet a VM. (I have a special public IP for it). I can also allow only one port (the HTTP).

I tryied to follow that http://forum.ovh.com/9showthread.php?t=49217 , it works but it is very slow .. (when I use tse on the VM it is really fast)

Do you have a solution ?

My configuration : the host is windows 2012 standard. the client is windows 2003

regards

Comment: "It works but it is very slow": so the problem actually seems to be "how to increase a hyper-V VM performance", and not what is shown in the title.

Comment: Actually not, it is even more on the line "m network is crap, help". Noone says this is hyper-v. if i read it right it could be a crappy internet connection (works fast locally).

Comment: you'd have to work real hard at screwing up a hyper-v installation to make it slow down an internet connection, my gut feeling is that its not the problem. Like TomTom said its a bad internet setup of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Problem? I mean, I have just done it. Put the Network up so that the IP "can be valid" and just bind it in the VM. I run a VLAN with my Internet space in my data Server room so I can just hook a VM to the VLAN by ID and use public IP's.

This smells a lot like not being in any way related to Hyper-V.

Comment: well it is related. when I was connected to the host server with TSE and when I use the hyper v manager to show the instance (within TSE) and when I use Internet explorer to show the web page, it was really fast. But when I access directly with the ip, it was very slow. So it isn't a problem of ressources affected to the VM but a problem of network configuration. I followed the instruction on the link I gave (in the host, basically I created an internal network and I created a route). Then I managed to create an external network and it works.